# Gridview - Is it necessary to grab data from database every time a filter, sort, or paging event occurs?

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview

Regarding gridviews that are not bound to a Data Source Control:

In most GridView tutorials that I have seen, when just about any GridView event occurs, the end of the event handler will include BindDataGrid().

In some form, these BindDataGrid() functions 1) Grab data from the database 2) Assign any Filter or Sort expressions to the data, and 3) Bind the gridview to that data source (usually a DataView or DataTable.

Is there a better way to provide filterable & sortable data to a GridView without having to hit the database so often?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on how big your result set is.  If you are displaying page 3 of 1000, and user choose to resort by a different column, you have no choice but to hit the DB and get the appropriate data for page 3 given the new sort order.

Comment: @Roman - Doesn't this assume that the stored procedure is only returning 1 page worth of data? What about the case where all pages of data are brought down from the DB on the first query?

Comment: It does assume you only bring back the subset of data you plan to display, why would you bring back more?  If you wanted to avoid doing a DB hit every time you could enable asp.net caching and store the query/sp results in the cache (with appropriate expiration policies).

Comment: Why? Sometimes it takes a lot longer to code something to bring back a subset. Not to mention when you throw in filtering and custom sorting, things can get a bit complex. Implementation time is significantly faster, albeit runs slower if you bring in the full datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either Database Caching or Output Caching, otherwise you will have to pull from the database often.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery ? :-)

Comment: Where is the data being stored between postbacks?